# Magento 2 stage

Tags: magento2.3, testing

We have a multiple sites on our system but as far as i have been told in stage you can only have 1 store view at a time. We used to have a developer helping us and he was changing something somewhere to change the store view when we did changes.

Been trying to reach the developer to teach me how to redirect to the correct store view. Is there anyone here that know where this can be done? I understand my information is quite small but hopefully someone here knows what i am talking about.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to **admin->store->all store**

https://drops.meetanshi.com/r7su2x

Check the number of stores here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to change store front, for some reason i needed to change a value in .htaccess file in SSH. When i change the old page to the new page i manage to point magento to the correct store front.